# facebook API limitations (iframe)

Tags: facebook, iframe, graph

On sign-up (i.e. when accessing the app), we need to get user's permission to invite their friends to use the app. When a user has finished using the app and the picture displays on their wall, we need to share the post with all of their friends automatically

Can this be done in FB application running from iframe? What would be the easiest approach to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't automatically send out invites. You can [present the user with a form](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form) to pick friends to invite, but your app can't do it on their behalf.

Comment: You'd probably best familiarize yourself with the documentation if you plan on writing a Facebook app. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#requests

Comment: Ok. So I wrote the code from the documentation in the iframe (http://apps.facebook.com/gajuskuizinas/) but it does not render any content.

Comment: Okay. I got it. I need to use xfbml to do that.